# Python list, take even elements and odd elements to their own respective new lists

Tags: python, list, append, element

I am working on a problem wherein I paste a set of numbers, and I want to put the even and odd list elements from these numbers and put them in their own list, then add them together for a 3rd list.

Here is my code:

```
#list of numbers
start = """ 
601393 168477
949122 272353
944397 564134
406351 745395
281988 610822
451328 644000
198510 606886
797923 388924
470601 938098
578263 113262
796982 62212
504090 378833
"""

x = start.split()
#turn string into list elements then append to a list
step_two = []

step_two.append(x)

print step_two
# doublecheck that step_two is a list with all the numbers
step_three = step_two[1::2]
#form new list that consists of all the odd elements
print step_three
#form new list that consists of all the even elements
step_four = step_two[0::2]

print step_four
#add ascending even/odd element pairs together and append to new list
final_step = [x + y for x, y in zip(step_three, step_four)]

print final_step
```

This code yields these results:

"""
"Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[['601393', '168477', '949122', '272353', '944397', '564134', '406351',     '745395'
, '281988', '610822', '451328', '644000', '198510', '606886', '797923', '388924'
, '470601', '938098', '578263', '113262', '796982', '62212', '504090', '378833']
]

[]

[['601393', '168477', '949122', '272353', '944397', '564134', '406351', '745395'
, '281988', '610822', '451328', '644000', '198510', '606886', '797923', '388924'
, '470601', '938098', '578263', '113262', '796982', '62212', '504090', '378833']
]

[]

"""

Why is my list in step_three and step_four not working? I am not sure why my [::] functions aren't registering.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

You were too explicit here in step two:

```
x = start.split()
#turn string into list elements then append to a list
step_two = []

step_two.append(x)
```

`x` is already the `list` you need. `step_two` creates a new `list` and adds the previous `list` to it, so instead of `['601393', '168477',...]`, you have `[['601393', '168477',...]]`.

To fix this, simply call the split string `step_two` and proceed from there:

```
step_two = start.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your lists don't split the numbers into odd and even is that your code assumes that the list alternates between them - you take every other index for each list generation, but the numbers aren't arranged that way in the original string.
You'll need to do an 'evenness' test:

```
step_two = start.split()
step_three = []
step_four = []

for item in step_two:
    if int(item) % 2: # If it divides evenly by two, it returns 0, or False
        step_three.append(item)
    else:
        step_four.append(item)
```

The lists `step_three` and `step_four` will now correctly contain only odds or evens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would generate the odd list, hope it helps!

```
import sys

# Provided main(), calls mimic_dict() and mimic()
def main():



#list of numbers
  start = '601393 168477 949122 272353 944397 564134 406351 745395 281988 610822 451328 644000 198510 606886 797923 388924470601 938098 578263 113262 796982 62212 504090 378833'

  x = start.split()
    #turn string into list elements then append to a list
  step_two = []
  # gives you 23 items in your list "step_two" instead of 1 item with original append on it's own
  for s in x:
   step_two.append(s)

  #print (step_two)

 # print (step_two)
# doublecheck that step_two is a list with all the numbers
  i = 1
  step_three_odd_list = []
  while i < len(step_two):
    currentodditem = step_two[i]
    step_three_odd_list.append(currentodditem)
    i = i + 2
#form new list that consists of all the odd elements
  print (step_three_odd_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [::] that you have going on are extended slices, not tests for even and odd:
https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html

Also, since those numbers are in a string, when you split them you end up with strings, not integers that you test with math. So, you need to convert them to integers.

This post clued me in on a quick even/odd test: [Check if a number is odd or even in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837208/check-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even-in-python)

This code seems to do what you want, if I understand it correctly:

```
start = """ 
601393 168477
949122 272353
944397 564134
406351 745395
281988 610822
451328 644000
198510 606886
797923 388924
470601 938098
578263 113262
796982 62212
504090 378833
"""

# List comprehension to generate a list of the numbers converted to integers
step_two = [int(x) for x in start.split()]
# Sort the list
step_two.sort()

# Create new lists for even and odd
even_numbers = []
odd_numbers = []

# For each item in the list, test for even or odd and add to the right list
for number in step_two:
    if (number % 2 == 0):
         #even
         even_numbers.append(number)
    else:
        #odd
        odd_numbers.append(number)

print(even_numbers)
print(odd_numbers)

final_step = [x + y for x, y in zip(even_numbers, odd_numbers)]

print(final_step)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehensions` to create two lists `odd` and `even` :

```
import itertools
start = """ 
601393 168477
949122 272353
944397 564134
406351 745395
281988 610822
451328 644000
198510 606886
797923 388924
470601 938098
578263 113262
796982 62212
504090 378833
"""
lst = start.split()
even = [int(i) for i in lst if int(i) % 2 == 0]
odd = [int(i) for i in lst if int(i) % 2 != 0]
```

Then you can `zip` these 2 lists but as `even` and `odd` are not the same length, you have to use `itertools.zip_longest()` in Python 3 and `itertools.izip_longest()` in Python 2. You will then have a list of tuples:

```
final_step = [i for i  in itertools.zip_longest(even,odd)]
[(949122, 601393),
 (564134, 168477),
 (281988, 272353),
 (610822, 944397),
 (451328, 406351),
 (644000, 745395),
 (198510, 797923),
 (606886, 470601),
 (388924, 578263),
 (938098, 378833),
 (113262, None),
 (796982, None),
 (62212, None),
 (504090, None)]
```

You can create the third list `result` to `sum()` the values using an other `list comprehension` but you have to make sure not to try to `sum` the tuples where one value is `None`.

```
result = [sum(e) if e[1] is not None else e[0] for e in final_step]
```

The final output:

```
[1550515,
 732611,
 554341,
 1555219,
 857679,
 1389395,
 996433,
 1077487,
 967187,
 1316931,
 113262,
 796982,
 62212,
 504090]
```