# How do I convert some elements of my for loop into lowercase?

Tags: python, lowercase

I'm currently following a Python course in uni, I just started like a week ago. For this exercise I need to print 'Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo' using a for loop. I have the following:

```
a = "Buffalo"
for req in range(0,8,1):
    print(a,end=" ")
```

This results in 8x Buffalo, but the 2nd,4th,5th,6th and 8th buffalo should be in lowercase. Can anyone tell me how to do this? I can't find it anywhere online

Comment: You cannot find it online because you have to think for yourself and solve the problem. Decompose the problem into smaller logical units and work you way up.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I had a really hard time coming up with the answer to this one. I will do more so from now on!

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a for loop (as you are already doing) for particular number of times and you need to alternate the printing of your `str` (1st, 3rd, 5th => 'Buffalo' and 2nd 4th 6th => 'buffalo').

You can either use a flag (`bool`) which you can toggle in each iteration and then use it's value to print the `str` alternatively

Or

make use of the `number` `i` in your for loop. The value in `i` always alternate between even and odd in every iteration. You can use this property.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21837292/5735010) answer to know how to check for even or odd. This is one of the way and resembles `c` way of checking even odd.

Try this:

```
a = "Buffalo"
for i in range(0, 8):
    if i & 1:
        print(a.lower(), end = ' ')
    else:
        print(a, end = ' ')
print()
```

Using Bitwise AND operator (copied from the answer mentioned in the link)

- The idea is to check whether the last bit of the number is set or not. If last bit is set then the number is odd, otherwise even.
- If a number is odd & (bitwise AND) of the Number by 1 will be 1, because the last bit would already be set. Otherwise it will give 0 as output.

Comment: But he is asking for 2, 4, 5, 6, and 8. That is not all even or odd, so your suggestion doesn't replicate what he is asking for

Comment: Edited and added explanation. Thanks!