# Question about Pascal's Triangle generator

Tags: python, pascals-triangle

I am a Python beginner and I have written a code for generating "Pascal's Triangle"

```py
from math import factorial
n = 50

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n-i+1):

        print(end=" ")

    for j in range(i+1):

        print(factorial(i)//(factorial(j)*factorial(i-j)), end=" ")

    print()
```

but, now I want to go bit further by changing the even Entries of the of the triangle to 0 and odd entries to 1, so

```
1

11

121

1331

14641
```

will become

```
1

11

101

1111

10001
```

so, what changes do I have to do in my code for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a number is odd or even in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837208/check-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even-in-python)

Comment: So basically just `factorial(i)//(factorial(j)*factorial(i-j)) % 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just instead of printing `value` you need to print `value & 1`, as in following code.

`value & 1` gives a lower bit of an integer, which is also the same as `value % 2` (remainder of division by 2), this bit is equal `1` if number is odd and `0` if it is even.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BCsIwEETv@xVDD5JVSy3iRejHBG3sBrMJIRe/PrYKUqFz23nMzKZXmaKea3U5BgRbJkhIMRc4eysxi32SYsDlRORihkAU2epjNMpXwqzF9iu7lUM/ow9blLJoMaPehwYN01ZmM2F@Hxjhrludnvcr1npmxg79Ef8j3xqmWt8)

```py
from math import factorial
n = 50

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n-i+1):

        print(end=" ")

    for j in range(i+1):

        print((factorial(i)//(factorial(j)*factorial(i-j))) & 1, end=" ")

    print()
```

Output:

```
                                                   1 
                                                  1 1 
                                                 1 0 1 
                                                1 1 1 1 
                                               1 0 0 0 1 
                                              1 1 0 0 1 1 
                                             1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
                                            1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                                           1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
                                          1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
                                         1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
                                        1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
                                       1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
                                      1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
                                     1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
                                    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                                   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
                                  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
                                 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
                                1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
                               1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
                              1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
                             1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
                            1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                           1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
                          1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
                         1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
                        1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
                       1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
                      1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
                     1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
                    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
                  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
                 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
                1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
               1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
              1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
             1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
            1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
           1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
          1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
         1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
        1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
       1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
      1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
     1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

---

Just for fun, if one prints `#` instead of 1 and space instead of 0, as in [this code](https://tio.run/##bY7BCsIwEETv@YqhgslqSy3iReiXiIegrd1iNyHk4tfHVkEidG47j5lZ/4qDk2NKfXATJhsH8ORdiOjtLbrA9qkELU4HpXoXwGBBsPLojNBZYdZij5ld8b6Z0Yct8oElmk7ubYGC1FpmNWE0dAm90XQxv2cMU11n50i7jFUjEWGL5lrif/BbSSqlNw), then you'll get a nice picture of fractal:

```
                                                   # 
                                                  # # 
                                                 #   # 
                                                # # # # 
                                               #       # 
                                              # #     # # 
                                             #   #   #   # 
                                            # # # # # # # # 
                                           #               # 
                                          # #             # # 
                                         #   #           #   # 
                                        # # # #         # # # # 
                                       #       #       #       # 
                                      # #     # #     # #     # # 
                                     #   #   #   #   #   #   #   # 
                                    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
                                   #                               # 
                                  # #                             # # 
                                 #   #                           #   # 
                                # # # #                         # # # # 
                               #       #                       #       # 
                              # #     # #                     # #     # # 
                             #   #   #   #                   #   #   #   # 
                            # # # # # # # #                 # # # # # # # # 
                           #               #               #               # 
                          # #             # #             # #             # # 
                         #   #           #   #           #   #           #   # 
                        # # # #         # # # #         # # # #         # # # # 
                       #       #       #       #       #       #       #       # 
                      # #     # #     # #     # #     # #     # #     # #     # # 
                     #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   # 
                    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
                   #                                                               # 
                  # #                                                             # # 
                 #   #                                                           #   # 
                # # # #                                                         # # # # 
               #       #                                                       #       # 
              # #     # #                                                     # #     # # 
             #   #   #   #                                                   #   #   #   # 
            # # # # # # # #                                                 # # # # # # # # 
           #               #                                               #               # 
          # #             # #                                             # #             # # 
         #   #           #   #                                           #   #           #   # 
        # # # #         # # # #                                         # # # #         # # # # 
       #       #       #       #                                       #       #       #       # 
      # #     # #     # #     # #                                     # #     # #     # #     # # 
     #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #                                   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   # 
    # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                                 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
   #                               #                               #                               # 
  # #                             # #                             # #                             # #
```

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I needed!!! Thank you !!!!

Comment: @ThunderWolf Just updated my answer, added Part 2 where I draw a nice fractal out of your Triangle, please put a look :)