# how to control the range of loop

Tags: python, loops

I want to print a pattern of triangles, first normal triangle and then inverted triangle in one line.
I wrote the following code, and it was printing the required output, but the number of triangles printing are not as I wanted to be.

```
a = int(input("enter the height of triangle: "))
b =int(input("how many triangles you want??"))
for i in range(1 ,a+1):
    print(" "*(a+1 -i), end="")
    for j in range(1,b+1):
        print("* "*i,end="")
        print(" ",end="")
        print("* "*(a+1-i),end="")
        print(" ",end=" ")
    print()
```

I tried to change the range for j loop from b+1 to b/2 +1. Here is my current code:

```py
a = int(input("enter the height of triangle: "))
b =int(input("how many triangles you want??"))
c = int(b/2)
for i in range(1 ,a+1):
    print(" "*(a+1 -i), end="")
    for j in range(1,c+1):
        print("* "*i,end="")
        print(" ",end="")
        print("* "*(a+1-i),end="")
        print(" ",end=" ")
    print()
```

This only works if I input an even number for number of triangles to be printed. If I want to print 9 triangles, it will print only 8 and I think this is happening because of that int conversion I did explicitly above, but now I don't know how to solve this problem.

Can someone explain what is the issue with odd number of triangles?

Comment: Welcome.. your triangles are always printed in pairs. If you want odd number of triangles you need to change the logic. `c = int(b/2)` will not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when you have a an odd number of triangles, you dont want to add the final `*`s in to each row. First you have to check if `b` is odd and this can be easily done with the [modulo operator `%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21837247/14536215). Then in the inner loop we add a condition to check if the `*`s are for the last triangle and if b is odd. If it is, we `break` out of the inner loop. <s>I also switch the assignment for `c` to use `round` instead, which will do the mathematically correct rounding, i.e. NN.5 will be rounded upwards.</s>I add +1 to `c` if `b` is odd to avoid [floating point accuracy issue](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) with `round(9/2) -> 4)`.

```py
a = int(input("enter the height of triangle: "))
b = int(input("how many triangles you want??"))
b_is_odd = b % 2 != 0  # True if b is odd, otherwise False
c = int(b/2)
if b_is_odd:
    c += 1
for i in range(1 ,a+1):
    print(" "*(a+1 -i), end="")
    for j in range(1,c+1):
        print("* "*i,end="")
        print(" ",end="")
        # Stop the inner loop before printing final triangle if b is odd
        if j == c and b_is_odd:
            break
        print("* "*(a+1-i),end="")
        print(" ",end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: hey! thanks for answering, actually i wanted that, if i input b to be 9 i.e i want 9 triangles to be printed, but the problem in my code was if i input 9, it still gonna print 8, so i want it to be exactly 9.

Comment: @rahulbachheti I updated my answer, there was an issue with float accuracy. Now it works with 9 triangles as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i just figured out the same logic, thanks to you. 
Thanks for answering also.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with a different format, you can just flip the nested loop around:

```
a = int(input("enter the height of triangle: "))
b =int(input("how many triangles you want??"))

for i in range(1,b+1):
    for j in range(1,a+1):
        print(" "*(a-j)+" *"*j+"\n",end="")
```

Tested in Jupyter:

[image]

Comment: hey, actually i wanted the triangles to be in single line, i.e horizontally, Tzane already provided a solution to problem, you can check that out.